# AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to print the objects of file to screen line by line.  Here is my code any help is appreciated.

```
filename = input("What file would you like to open? ")
filename = filename + ".txt"
openfile = open(filename,"r")
for line in filename.readlines():
  print(line)
```

Here is my full code everything runs fine except when I am trying to print the contents of file line by line.

```
import menumodule
mainMenuOptions = ("create new file","add person to existing file","display contents of a file","exit")

choice = menumodule.getMenuNumber(mainMenuOptions)

if choice == "create new file":
  filename = input("What is the name of the file? ")
  filename = filename + ".txt"
  openfile = open(filename,"w")
  openfile.close()
  print("The " + filename + " file has been created.")

if choice == "add person to existing file":
  filename = input("What file would you like to open? ")
  filename = filename + ".txt"
  from pathlib import Path
  if Path(filename).exists():
    openfile = open(filename,"w")
    firstName = input("What is your first name? ")
    lastName = input("What is your last name? ")
    firstLast = firstName + " " + lastName
    with open(filename, "a") as file1:
      x = firstLast.center(48)
      file1.write("\n \n ************************************************** \n *                                                * \n *                                                * \n *" + x + "* \n *                                                * \n *                                                * \n **************************************************")
  else:
    print("That file does not exist.")

if choice == "display contents of a file":
  filename = input("What file would you like to open? ")
  filename = filename + ".txt"
  print(filename)
  openfile = open(filename,"r")
  for line in filename.readlines():
    print(line)
```

Comment: Please provide the string that you are providing to the input.

Comment: I added my full code if that helps.  :)  Thank you

Comment: You mean `for line in openfile.readlines():`, although `for line in openfile:` will work as well since file objects can be iterated.